# Prototyped collection view cell "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints." warning

Tags: ios, storyboard, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I am using storyboards in my application and I have prototyped my cell with constraints. However, I want to size my cell based on the screen size so I am giving them a size using this callback method:

```
- (CGSize) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(self.photosCollectionView.frame.size.width-15, self.photosCollectionView.frame.size.width+40);
}
```

When I do this it gives the big warning "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" which is in a lot of posts on stack. I have tried a lot of things I have read such as removing the constraints using `[cell.contentview setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];`
 but then my cell subviews end up all over the place. Please if anyone has any suggestions let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had to do this when I dequeue the cell:

```
[cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
[cell layoutIfNeeded];
```